# error: include of non-modular header inside framework module for cocoapods spec

Tags: swift, frameworks, repository, cocoapods, podspec

I saw the similar issue in stackoverflow, and add `--use-libraries` after `pod spec lint`. It just says 
`[!] Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; this feature is still in beta. Add`use_frameworks!`to your Podfile or target to opt into using it.` It very strange.

My question is how to create a framework which is written in objective-c and swift, and create a private cocoapods repository. I cannot create a correct .podspec because I use objective-c bridging header in framework, and `pod spec lint` always tell me `error: include of non-modular header inside framework module`. This makes me gonna be crazy...

I also post this issue in detail in github:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3666

If anyone knows how to fix it, I'll be very appreciate for you. Thanks a lot!